# Is the extended Euclidean algorithm the most efficient way to invert modulo p?

Tags: finite-fields, inverse

Is there any latest afford done, in this topic or is the EEA still the most efficient way to invert an element, say of size $2^{340}$?

If there is any better way, could you link me to the article or just tell me the google phrase?

If there is any special kind for $p\equiv - 3 \bmod 8$, this would be awesome.

Comment: If you have to invert many elements modulo the same $p$ I think using Euler's theorem with Montgomery modular multiplication is the fastest.

Comment: The extended euclidean algorithm is already very efficient. It is almost certain the fastest algorithm in general.

Comment: Modular inversion is, indeed, the bottleneck (ok, that may be an exaggeration) for some operations. For example elliptic curve crypto primitives. That's why they consider alternatives such as projective coordinates. (when you can cut down the number of divisions). May be something like that can help in your application, too?

Comment: That might be possible. I'm implementing a pairing-operation on the KSS16 curve and designing the GF(p) operations. Since one 32-Bit Mul is cost-equal to an addition (both hardware implemented and consumes 1 cycle) the design decision is a bid easier. I guess, that I won't will require GF(p) inversions, but $GF(p^{16})$. But I'm interested in doing an inversion. Maybe those information get you to a point, to make specific recommendations.

Comment: @orlp I did not found any algorithm that takes "A,B" and returns "$A\cdot B\bmod p$". The only thing I found about the Monti is, that I can efficiently compute the mod p part. So the multiplication does not depend on the Monti. Btw. it turned out, that the schoolbook multiplication of polynomials is the most efficient algorithm, that could be used.